# Is there a bulk load option from an array into MonetDBe

Tags: sql, bulkinsert, monetdb

I am implementing MonetDBe as an integrated DB in my server.
I want to have the ability to load bulk data into the database. Looking at the MonetDB documentation there is a CopyInto SQL command that allows the loading of bulk data from csv files.

As MonetDBe is embedded in my application I would ideally like to bulk load data into MonetDB from internal data arrays.

My data will normally come from my client application, which sends the data over a WebSocket. This means that I receive the data as a const Char Array.  What would be the quickest way of loading this data into MonetDB.  i.e. is there a CopyInto Command I could use, or would I have to use the standard select into the command>

Answer (score 0):

Look at `monetdbe_append()`. declared in `monetdbe.h` as

```
char* monetdbe_append(
    monetdbe_database dbhdl,
    const char* schema, const char* table,
    monetdbe_column **input, size_t column_count);
```

Each `monetdbe_column` will contain a type indication and a pointer to an array of data values. For date/time related types, use the structs declared at the top of the file.